# Python capture events when console has focus with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm building a console app, and would like to capture keystrokes in real time. The following code works perfectly until another window gets focus. From that point on, I'm not able to get back to a state where I can capture keystrokes and other events again with only the console visible.

```
import tkinter as tk
app = tk.Tk()

def handleKeypress(event):
    key = event.char
    if(key == 'q'):
        app.destroy()
    else:
        print(key)

app.bind_all('<Key>', handleKeypress)
app.withdraw()
app.mainloop()
```

I've tried using various methods (grab and focus) to redirect the focus to my app. The best I was able to do was to get the Tkinter window visible and in focus with `deiconify()`, but I was not able to hide it again to make it as though the console is the only window.

Adding the following results in the Tkinter window appearing and disappearing repeatedly:

```
def lostFocus(event):
    app.deiconify()
    app.focus_force()
    app.withdraw()

app.bind_all('<FocusOut>', lostFocus)
```

How can I go back to the state the application was in right after launch? Or even better, how can I force it to get all events without having to make the Tkinter window visible and in focus?

Comment: Have you tried `app.grab_set()`?

Comment: Yes, I have. It doesn't seem to change anything. I've also tried `grab_set_global()` with the same result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do what you want. Tkinter is designed -- as are most GUI toolkits -- to only process events when it has the focus. That's the whole point of focus: for the OS to know where to send events.

The fact that it works initially is probably a bug in tkinter. Though, perhaps it can be explained by the fact that the window initially has focus, and when you withdraw the window the OS doesn't move the focus

The only way to restore focus is to make the window visible.